# Batch script to copy symbolic links as is but not overwrite source if already exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, robocopy

I've tried Fastcopy and Robocopy and both seem to be able to do either one of those operation but not both.

For files like (BEFORE COPYING)

```
D:\SYMLINKSOURCE\file1 <<symlink from D:\Source\file1 **edit
D:\SYMLINKSOURCE\file2 <<symlink from D:\Source\file1 **edit

D:\DESTINATIONxx\file2 <<not a symlink
```

I want to copy `D:\SYMLINKSOURCE\*` to `D:\DESTINATIONxx` but without overwriting `D:\DESTINATIONxx\file1` such that after copying it looks like

```
(AFTER COPYING)
D:\SYMLINKSOURCE\file1 <<symlink from D:\Source\file1
D:\SYMLINKSOURCE\file2 <<symlink from D:\Source\file2

D:\DESTINATIONxx\file1 <<symlink from D:\Source\file1
D:\DESTINATIONxx\file2 <<not a symlink
```

I tried this to not overwrite but it doesn't preserve Symbolic links and instead copies resolved files [Copy files without overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228807/copy-files-w-o-overwrite)

```
robocopy "D:\SYMLINKSOURCE" "D:\DESTINATION" /E /XC /XN /XO

(AFTER COPYING)
D:\SYMLINKSOURCE\file1 <<symlink from D:\Source\file1
D:\SYMLINKSOURCE\file2 <<symlink from D:\Source\file2

D:\DESTINATIONxx\file1 <<not a symlink < i wanted this as symlink
D:\DESTINATIONxx\file2 <<not a symlink
```

and adding /SL to preserve symlinks overwrites everything.

```
robocopy "D:\SYMLINKSOURCE" "D:\DESTINATION" /E /XC /XN /XO /SL

(AFTER COPYING)
D:\SYMLINKSOURCE\file1 <<symlink from D:\Source\file1
D:\SYMLINKSOURCE\file2 <<symlink from D:\Source\file2

D:\DESTINATIONxx\file1 <<symlink from D:\Source\file1
D:\DESTINATIONxx\file2 <<symlink from D:\Source\file1 < i did not want this overwritten
```

Is there any way I can achieve what I want?

Comment: O_o symbolic links and batch? Don't these two belong to two different operating systems?

Comment: NTFS support both symbolic and hardlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see on how to do this would be to use two seperate robocopy's first for the non-link files and later for the link-files you want to copy as links. Assuming that there are more normal files than links, you could run your:

```
robocopy "D:\SYMLINKSOURCE" "D:\DESTINATION" /E /XC /XN /XO
```

Then copying the actual links by naming the individually (or using some naming convention, like `sl-file1` and usa a `sl*` pattern) and thus fixing the erroneously overwritten links with:

```
robocopy "D:\SYMLINKSOURCE\file1" "D:\DESTINATION" /E /XC /XN /XO /SL
```