# How to add files to zip without overwriting if already exists in batch script with 7zip

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I'm writing a script that is adding some files to an existing zip with 7zip, but if there is a file match the file inside the zip will be overwritten. I don't want that, if the file with the same name is already there i want to skip it.

My code now is something like that:

```
%zipPath% a %zipfile%  "%%~F"
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Are you on windows or linux (it might not affect the solution but sometimes command arguments/options syntax could vary) Seems like it's windows actually, with `%` syntax :)

Comment: Seems like it is not supported. You might need to extract, then robocopy (`robocopy c:\Sourcepath c:\Destpath /E /XC /XN /XO` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4228925/1012381) the new files then archive the result

Comment: You can list the files through `find or findstr` and detect the filename of the file you want to add.  If it exists, abort, if not then go ahead and repack the file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a complete set of options to determine how to update the contents of the file. See `-u (update options)` in 7z help. The parameters you probably need are

`7z a -up1q1r2x1y1z1w1 zipfile filesToAdd`

Which keeps in archive (the 1 in the switch) files in case of no match (p), file does not exist on disk (q), file in archive is newer than on disk (x), file in archive is older than on disk (y), file in archive is the same that on disk (z), or if it can't be determined (w). In case of file not in archive (r), it is compressed (2).

Seems complicated, but it is perfectly documented in 7zip help.

Comment: Yes, just figured it out :D THX

Comment: Here's an online version of the documentation for `-u`: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/update.htm

Comment: any idea how to customize these options using its GUI?

Comment: I used the switch -up1q1r2x1y1z1w1 to add new files to an existinng 7Z file, from the same directory that it was created. It's size,  from 45MB became **104MB**, which was not OK.  It should be only 58MB, which is the size when I create a new 7Z file, from scratch, with all the files (old+new)! I checked the &Z file and saw that **the whole directory was stored within itself!!** Hence it's double size.
How do you explain this?

Comment: @Apostolos the indicated parameters only control the strategy on how to handle how to update the archive, but you are not including the rest of the arguments you have used that could cause the  whole folder to be added to the archive

Comment: I don't undestand what you are saying. **I have used your example exactly as it is**. Does your example work or not?  And, you dodn't answer my question: "How do you explain that?". In other words, **what exactly** is in your parameters that produces this phenomenon?  Which BTW I have never seen before.

Comment: @apostolos there are more parameters that can indicate how to handle file and folder selection. You can add a set of files from a directory and you can also add the directory itself with the contained files, both operations are not the same, how you pass arguments, how you indicate what to store also matters