# Autoit FileCopy to update only new files

Tags: file, copy, autoit

Im trying to copy files from a folder using

```
FileCopy($Source & "*.*,$Dest",8)
```

Since the source folder has huge files and every hour new files gets added, i wanted to copy only the newer files (not present in the destination directory)

I don't want to use overwrite(9) option to avoid unwanted copying.

But if I don't use the overwrite filecopy stops updating new files (guess it stops the moment it finds an source file existing on destination directory)

Is there any other built-in function that just skips overwriting and still copies the new files???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not writing it yourself? _FileListToArray [local] - then Loop through the files - if Not FileExists(...)[remote] Then FileCopy. That's it. If you are not able. Let me know and I post an example.

Comment: YEp..I can do that...but i thought this is a very basic thing which should be available as part of some of the standard functions .Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want it for backup.
The one liner in autoit would be:

```
Runwait(@ComSpec & " /c " & "xcopy " & '"' & $source & '"' & ' "' & $destination & '"' & " /E /C /D /Y","",@SW_HIDE)
```

- Will not overwrite unless the source file is newer(/D).
- Will create directory structure, even the empty ones(/E).
- Will copy hidden files (/H).
- Will not stop on errors(/C).

For example:

```
$source = "D:\PROGRAMING BRE !!!"
$destination = "M:\PROGRAMING BRE !!!"
$timer = TimerInit()

Runwait(@ComSpec & " /c " & "xcopy " & '"' & $source & '"' & ' "' & $destination & '"' & " /E /C /D /Y /H /J","",@SW_HIDE)

MsgBox(0,"","Done in " & TimerDiff($timer)/1000 & " seconds!")
```

---

While this is not a pure Autoit, but an implementation of XCOPY it does the job very well.

Its lightning fast!

> 1GB 18.020 Files, 2.224 Folders **38sec!**

To recheck all those files and add new ones **2sec!**

Comment: Thanks Milos! I implemented pretty much the same as you mentioned but using robocopy
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228807/copy-files-w-o-overwrite

Comment: Robocopy has more options, but what about the speed?