# Understanding batch files

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to understand a pretty complex (to me it is anyhow) batch file that somebody else has written.

The person who wrote it is no longer around so it's down to me to try and figure out what the hell is going on.

To start with, I need to understand what this line is doing: -

```
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1,5" %%A in ('dir /tc /o-d %i%\PICKS*') do (
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: So you need to Google a lot. Those batch commands are well documented. See for example the [dir](https://www.windows-commandline.com/dir-command-line-options/) command: dir /TC will get you the created time of a file. Have also a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) documentation page for more info about the for command.

Comment: to start with run [`for /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and [`dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) in your cmd and read the output

Answer (score 3):

### 1. How to get help on Windows commands?

Help on any Windows standard command can be get by running the command with parameter `/?` from within a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window.

Try it out with executing in a command prompt window `dir /?` and `for /?`.

Or run this long [command line with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564):

```
dir /? >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Help_on_DIR_FOR.txt" & for /? >>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Help_on_DIR_FOR.txt" & %SystemRoot%\Notepad.exe "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Help_on_DIR_FOR.txt"
```

This is like running the three command lines:

```
dir /? >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Help_on_DIR_FOR.txt"
for /? >>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Help_on_DIR_FOR.txt"
%SystemRoot%\Notepad.exe "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Help_on_DIR_FOR.txt"
```

It runs command **DIR** to output its help with redirecting the help into file `Help_on_DIR_FOR.txt` on the desktop. Next it runs command **FOR** to output its help with appending it to file `Help_on_DIR_FOR.txt`. And last *Windows Notepad* is started to display the file `Help_on_DIR_FOR.txt`.

See the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for the details on the redirection operators `>` and `>>`.
See the Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) for the details on the predefined environment variables **UserProfile** and **SystemRoot**.

Other sources for help on Windows commands are:

1. [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
2. [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/)

### 2. What to know about text encoding of batch files?

The text in a batch file is encoded using one byte per character. That means on using *Windows Notepad* to create/edit a batch file it is necessary to make sure to save the batch file using **ANSI** encoding.

Text files using a text encoding with only one byte per character are limited to 256 characters. So there must be a table to define which byte value represents which character. There are many such tables as the mankind on this planet uses more than 256 characters. For text encoding the used [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) defines the table used for character encoding.

In a Windows command prompt window (console) is used by default an **OEM** ([Original Equipment Manufacturer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_equipment_manufacturer)) code page while in Windows GUI applications like *Windows Notepad* is used by default a Windows (ANSI) code page.

Which code page is used depends on Windows region setting as defined for the used account. For example in North American countries [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) is used for console and [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) by Windows GUI applications while in Western European countries [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) is used for console and also **Windows-1252** by Windows GUI applications.

Run in a command prompt window the command `chcp` to get displayed which code page is used on console according to region (country) set for your account.

The knowledge about code pages is important on writing a batch file using a Windows GUI editor which contains text with characters with a code value greater 127 decimal because for the upper half of the 256 characters the used code page defines which value represents which character.

It can be easily seen that all non ASCII characters of the help are displayed wrong in *Notepad* in case of not using English Windows and looking on help output for **DIR** and **FOR** to console redirected into a text file viewed with *Windows Notepad* because of the text file was not created using the Windows (ANSI) code page as expected by *Notepad*.

### 3. What does the command line ask for?

Let us analyze the command line

```
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1,5" %%A in ('dir /tc /o-d %i%\PICKS*') do (
```

by executing following commented batch file:

```
@echo off
rem Setup a local environment for the commands below.
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the directory to process.
set "i=%TEMP%\UnderstandingDirFor"

rem Create this directory temporarily.
md "%i%" 2>nul

rem Create a file with PICKS at beginning of file name in the directory.
echo PICKS_SampleFile.tmp>"%i%\PICKS Sample File.tmp"

rem Copy the batch file into directory with PICKS in file name.
copy "%~0" "%i%\PICKS_ExampleFile.bat" >nul

rem Copy another file into directory with PICKS in file name.
copy "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe" "%i%\PICKS cmd.exe" >nul

rem Copy a file into directory with a file name not starting with PICKS.
copy "%SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe" "%i%" >nul

cls
echo First output is from:
echo(
echo dir "%%i%%\PICKS*"
echo(
dir "%i%\PICKS*"
echo(
pause

echo(
echo ===============================================================================
echo(

echo Second output is from:
echo(
echo dir /tc /o-d "%%i%%\PICKS*"
echo(

dir /tc /o-d "%i%\PICKS*"

echo(
pause

echo(
echo ===============================================================================
echo(

echo Third output is from:
echo(
echo for /f "skip=4 tokens=1,5" %%%%I in ('dir /tc /o-d "%%i%%\PICKS*"')
echo(

for /f "skip=4 tokens=1,5" %%I in ('dir /tc /o-d "%i%\PICKS*"') do (
    echo Token 1 = loop variable I = %%I
    echo Token 5 = loop variable J = %%J
)

echo(
pause

echo(
echo ===============================================================================
echo(

echo Fourth output is from:
echo(
echo for /F "skip=5 tokens=1,4*" %%%%I in ('dir /A-D /O-D /TC "%%i%%\PICKS *" 2^^^>nul')
echo(

for /F "skip=5 tokens=1,4*" %%I in ('dir /A-D /O-D /TC "%i%\PICKS *" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%J" == "PICKS" (
        echo Token 1 = loop variable I = %%I
        echo Token 5 = loop variable K = %%K
    )
)

echo(
pause

rem Delete the created directory with the four files.
rd /S /Q "%i%"

rem Purge the local environment and restore initial environment.
endlocal
```

**Note:** The batch file uses `"%i%\PICKS*"` instead of `%i%\PICKS*` to work also for directory paths containing a space character or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. The path of the directory for temporary directories and files referenced with `%TEMP%` included in `%i%` could contain a space character which requires the usage of double quotes.

**The first output into console window is from:**

```
dir "%i%\PICKS*"
```

It can be seen on output that the files (or directories) matching the wildcard pattern `PICKS*` are listed with last modification date at beginning and in [order as used internally by the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44205461/3074564).

The file `sort.exe` is not output because it's file name does not start with `PICKS`.

What **DIR** outputs exactly depends on language of Windows. But the first five lines are the header and the last three lines are the summary in language of Windows.

**The second output into console window is from:**

```
dir /tc /o-d "%i%\PICKS*"
```

The output of the list is now in **reverse order by date/time** because of option `/o-d` using **creation date** because of the option `/tc`.

By default the file/directory with the oldest date is output first and the file/directory with the newest date is output last on using `/od`. The order is reverse with `/o-d` which means output is first the newest and last the oldest file/directory.

It can be seen on comparing the two outputs that the creation date of all copied files is newer than their last modification date.

The reason is that the creation date is the date a file/directory was **created in current directory** and **NOT** when the **file itself was created** the first time anywhere.

For that reason the creation date is most often not really useful and using the creation date might be also not useful here. But this can't be determined without knowing what the entire batch file is written for.

**The third output into console window is from:**

```
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1,5" %%I in ('dir /tc /o-d "%i%\PICKS*"') do (
    echo Token 1 = loop variable I = %%I
    echo Token 5 = loop variable J = %%J
)
```

**FOR** starts a new command process in background using `cmd.exe` with option `/C` for an automatic close for executing the specified command line `dir /tc /o-d "%i%\PICKS*"`. To be more precise there is executed by **FOR**:

```
%ComSpec% /c dir /tc /o-d "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\PICKS*"
```

`ComSpec` is a predefined environment variable with full qualified file name of Windows command processor which is usually `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`.

The output of the entire command process to handle **STDOUT** is captured by **FOR** and processed line by line after background command process finished and closed itself.

`for /F` ignores by default all empty lines. The other lines are by default first split up into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters which means no substring contains any space/tab. If the first space/tab delimited substring starts now with a semicolon being the default end of line character, the line is not further processed by **FOR** and so also ignored like an empty line. Then the first substring is assigned to specified loop variable and the single command or the command block is executed next.

Command **FOR** is instructed with option `skip=4` to skip the first four lines of captured output and start processing the output with line five which is the last empty line of header of **DIR** output.

Command **FOR** is instructed with option `tokens=1,5` to not assign only first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`, but also the fifth space/tab delimited string to the loop variable being the next one after `I` in [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) if there is a fifth substring (= token) at all which is loop variable `J`.

This substrings/tokens to loop variable assignments feature is the reason why loop variables are case-sensitive while environment variables are not case-sensitive.

Command **FOR** ignores a line if the first specified token as specified with `tokens=` cannot be determined from a line. But it does not ignore lines on which not all strings of interest can be found in line as it can be seen on third output.

What fifth space/tab delimited string assigned to loop variable `J` should be in original batch code depends on what the directory referenced with `%i%` contains - files or directories - and how the file/directory names starting case-insensitive with `PICKS` really look like.

For the example I assumed `PICKS*` matches files with file name starting with `PICKS`  (note the space at end) and more characters not containing a space character.

By looking on third output it can be seen that the names of the three `PICKS*` are not assigned all to loop variable `J` as expected and the summary lines are also processed.

I suppose this does not happen in original batch file because of file/directory names do not contain another space character after `PICKS` and the **FOR** loop is exited with command **GOTO** after processing first file/directory name.

**The fourth output into console window is from:**

```
for /F "skip=5 tokens=1,4*" %%I in ('dir /A-D /O-D /TC "%i%\PICKS *" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%J" == "PICKS" (
        echo Token 1 = loop variable I = %%I
        echo Token 5 = loop variable K = %%K
    )
)
```

This is an improved version suitable to output only the creation date and the name of the files in temporary directory matching the wildcard pattern.

The **DIR** option `/A-D` is added to ignore subdirectories and get just a list of files of which file name is matched by the wildcard pattern.

The wildcard pattern is modified to `PICKS *` which results in command **DIR** not outputting anymore a line for file `PICKS_ExampleFile.bat` because of the underscore instead of the space in the file name.

On **DIR** command line `2^>nul` is appended for suppressing a perhaps output error message. Command **DIR** outputs an error message to handle **STDERR** not processed by **FOR** and therefore written to console when it can't find a file matching the wildcard pattern in the specified directory or when the directory does not exist at all. This error message is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with caret character `^` to be interpreted first as literal character on parsing **FOR** command line by Windows command interpreter, but as redirection operator on execution of **DIR** command line in background command process.

The `skip` option of command **FOR** is modified to `skip=5` to skip the first 5 lines, i.e. the entire header block of command **DIR**.

The `tokens` option of command **FOR** is modified to `tokens=1,4*`. This results on lines containing a file name matching the wildcard pattern `PICKS *` in assigning creation date of file to loop variable `I`, `PICKS` to loop variable `J` and everything after the space(s) after `PICKS` in line without further splitting up on spaces/tabs to loop variable `K`.

The **IF** condition compares case-insensitive, because of `/I`, the string assigned to loop variable `J` with `PICKS` and outputs creation date and file name only if the compared strings are equal. This **IF** condition filters out the summary lines on output.

Because of `*` in `tokens=1,4*` the entire file name with the exception of `PICKS`  is output even if the file name contains more space characters like in `Sample File.tmp`.

### 4. How to debug a batch file?

Windows command processor outputs by default each command line respectively command block defined with `(` ... `)` after processing it before execution. The output of the command lines/blocks before execution can be disabled with using `@echo off` at top of the batch file whereby `@` prevents already the output of this command line.

But on debugging a batch file it is often necessary to see what is really executed. This can be achieved with either removing `@echo off`, or changing it to `@echo ON` or comment this command line out with `@rem @echo off` or with `::@echo off` whereby the last solution changes the command line into an invalid label line.

It is of course also possible to keep `@echo off` at top of the batch file and use inside the batch file `echo on` and some lines below `@echo off` to get displayed on execution just the commands between those two command lines to debug just a specific block of the batch file.

And for debugging the batch file it should not be executed by just double clicking on it in Windows Explorer. This results in starting `cmd.exe` implicit with option `/C` for executing the batch file and **close** the command process and therefore also the console window immediately on exiting the batch file execution.

The closing of the console window is not good for debugging a batch file because the executed commands can't be seen and also the error message output by Windows command processor on detecting a syntax error resulting in an immediate exit of batch file processing is not readable with console window automatically closed.

For that reason debugging a batch file should be done by opening a command prompt window which results in implicit execution of `cmd.exe` with option `/K` to **keep** command process running and its console window open after execution of the batch file which is entered with its file name and if needed with full path in the command prompt window for execution.

Another advantage of running the batch file from within a command prompt window is the possibility to use <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> keys to re-select a once entered command line or string entered on a user prompt within batch file with `set /P` from input buffer of command process.

Answer (score 0):

That's a for-loop with the /f option. It loops through a file or command, in this case the command `dir /tc /o-d %i%\PICKS*`.

Take a look at what `dir /tc /o-d word*` on its own does (read up on options wtih `dir /?`), it'll make understanding the loop easier.

Basically, the output of the command is `dir` (show files in directory) with the timefield showing the creation date and all files sorted by date in descending order. The command applies to the folder %i% (a variable set beforehand). "PICKS*" is the 'mask', i.e. all files starting with "PICKS" are shown. That's what the wildcard (asterisk) means (any characters can follow).

The for-loop now takes that output and assigns it to %%A (temporary iteration variable). It skips the first 4 lines (in the case of `dir` just header that you don't want to have), and for each following line (the files) picks out the first and the fifth word (delimited by spaces, as space is the default delimiter). %%A is now the date, %%B (the second specified token/fifth word) the second word of the filename (if there is any). Those variables can be used in the `do (...` part.

Comment: But in normal dir output the file name is the fourth token, so the fifth will only get filled if there is a space in the file name after `PICKS`

Comment: @LotPings some languages show the time as `AM` or `PM` (`08:00 PM` instead of `08:00`), which *might* explain the additional token. But agreed, this isn't safe for filenames with spaces.