# Windows command line wildcard expansion order

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wildcard, windows-console

When you issue the following copy with concatenation command in Windows:

```
copy /b *.txt elsewhere\all.txt
```

Is there any way to control the order of source files? A quick test suggests alphabetic sorting, but is there any guarantee?

Comment: You can control the order of the source files if you specify the order with the copy command. `copy foo.txt + bar.txt + file 3.txt all.txt`. Essentially you will have to programmatically create a string variable with the order of the files and use that variable with the `copy` command.

Comment: Honestly, the hassle of writing a piece of logic just to feed a string to `copy`, and the hassle of writing my own file concatenation piece is about the same :)

Comment: You can get most of the order by just using the `dir` command. It has several different sort orders you can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's no wildcard expansion in cmd like in bash. The command will receive the arguments as-is. In the `copy` command it passes the wildcard to [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) which returns files in whatever order the file system presents. In NTFS they're stored in a B-tree structure so if you use English it'll appear to be in alphabetic order, but it won't be like that in other languages or if there are special characters/special collocation rules. On a FAT32 drive files are stored linearly in the file allocation table so files would be listed in the order in that table

See

- [Default file order of "dir" command in Windows console](https://superuser.com/q/481570/241386)
- [What order does the DIR command arrange files if no sort order is specified?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140304-00/?p=1603)
- [How does Windows determine the order in which to copy files?](https://superuser.com/q/734436/241386)
- [In which order does command COPY copy files from source to destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44204762/995714)

Comment: For the record, on FAT32 the file records are not stored in the file allocation table per se; the table stores the blocks that the file occupies, but the directory itself (file names, attributes, starting block, etc). is kept elsewhere.